# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation missing “Integration Services” Shared feature in features selection step

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition in my system. The installation process is working perfectly except that in one of the steps where we are supposed to select the features, I observe that "Integration Services" shared feature IS MISSING in the features list.

I'm actually supposed to get the "Integration services" check box under the "shared features" list in feature selection step but i'm not getting it in my installation process.

Please check this link: https://amoghnatu.net/2013/10/07/question-help-required-sql-server-2008-r2-installation-missing-integration-services-shared-feature-in-features-selection-step/

I have posted the same question here along with screenshots of my installation procedure. The question would be more clearer if you see the screenshots.

Comment: That first screenshot suggests that you're installing Workgroup edition, not Enterprise Edition. Note the text below the title in both screenshots. `Select the XXX features to install` where `XXX` is different between them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I might have messed up with the ISO's while installations. I have one more question sir; 
Now that I have already installed SQL Server 2008 R2 work group edition; Suppose if I now run the setup of Enterprise edition and only install the integration services feature, will my database remain unchanged or will I lose all the data??

Comment: If you have an EE license (which you'll need, even if you only intend to add SSIS over what you've already installed), I'd recommend using the Edition upgrade feature of the installer first. User databases should be unaffected anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in fact installing the workgroup edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 and not the enterprise edition.

I started the installation again and when I entered the Enterprise Edition product registration key (instead of workgroup edition key) and navigated to the features selection page, Integration Services shared feature **was included** in the list.

Thanks to the commentators!